# lubridate adding a new column to add hour of the week

Tags: r, lubridate

I have this data frame;

```
  city                 date           
London  2022-01-01 00:00:00     
London  2022-01-01 01:00:00      
London  2022-01-01 02:00:00
London  2022-01-01 03:00:00
London  2022-01-01 04:00:00
London  2022-01-01 05:00:00
London  2022-01-01 06:00:00
...
London  2022-01-07 00:00:00
...
Glasgow 2022-01-01 00:00:00
Glasgow 2022-01-01 00:00:00
Glasgow 2022-01-01 00:00:00
...
```

I would like to group by city and add new column to called hour of the week.

where it shows;

```
  city                 date         hour of the week               
London  2022-01-01 00:00:00               0
London  2022-01-01 01:00:00               1   
London  2022-01-01 02:00:00               2
London  2022-01-01 03:00:00               3
London  2022-01-01 04:00:00               4
London  2022-01-01 05:00:00               5
London  2022-01-01 06:00:00               6
...
London  2022-01-07 23:00:00             167
...
Glasgow 2022-01-01 00:00:00               0
Glasgow 2022-01-01 01:00:00               1
Glasgow 2022-01-01 02:00:00               2
...
```

I have tried;
([day-1] * 24 + hour of abs)
which worked but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with lubridate. I have checked there is as.duration, but I couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: @akrun yes sorry that's my bad I have fixed it :)

Comment: Also, you have `Glasgow 2022-01-01 00:00:00` repeated 3 times.  Would that be 0 as well for the calculated column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate(date = ymd_hms(date), 
      hour_of_the_week = (day(date)-1) * 24 + hour(date))
```

Comment: thanks @akrun  this really helped. Although is there a way where it starts from 0 when it is 2022-01-08 00:00:00?

Comment: @Dome what will happen if the date is below that

Comment: So what I am trying to do is for every 7 days the hour of the day restarts again. so on 2022-01-08 it restarts from 0 till 167 (2022-01-14 23:00) and again restarts  0 when it is 2022-01-15 00:00. So I when I plot it, it can have multiple dots against hour if the time period is longer than one week.

Comment: @DomeDo you want `df1 %>% mutate(date = ymd_hms(date)) %>% arrange(city, date) %>% group_by(city, week_date = ceiling_date(date, "1 week")) %>% mutate( hour_of_the_week = row_number()-1 ) %>% ungroup` (if all them are in hourly basis)